# onclick increment number

Tags: javascript, onclick, numbers

With JavaScript, how can I do it so when I click a form button it adds 1 to a number?
The number it increments could be in a form text field or something.

Obviously it'd be on onclick but I'm not sure of the code.

Comment: onclick="form.field=form.field+1" I'm no good in javascript

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since you gave me nothing to start on, here is a simple example.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfprp/)

Example implementation:

```
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

Example Html

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```

Comment: user1022585, if you want to apply the same function to multiple elements you can add the input id as a parameter (i.e. `incrementValue( id )` ) and then change `getElementById( 'number' )` to `getElementById( id )`

Comment: Also if you are concerned about non-numeric input, you may want to alter this so that it doesn't convert any text it can't parse to NaN.  eg `if( value ){ document.getElement... }`

Answer (score 19):

**In its most basic incarnation..**

*JavaScript:*

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    function buttonClick() {
        document.getElementById('inc').value = ++i;
    }
</script>
```

*Markup:*

```
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Click Me</button>
<input type="text" id="inc" value="0"></input>
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/weERF/)

Comment: thank you. If I had a plus and a minus button, and about 4 of these, would I have to clone an edited version of the same function that many times too?

Comment: What happens if the value isn't numeric

Comment: @user1022585 not necessarily. You could pass parameters to the same function to encode what should happen.

Comment: @Gabe Probably something bad. But the value is never user input. Is this a problem meriting a downvote?

Comment: @paislee - how could it not be manipulated by a user input when the example itself is tied to a textbox

Answer (score 8):

## jQuery Example

```js
var $button = $('.increment-btn');
var $counter = $('.counter');

$button.click(function(){
  $counter.val( parseInt($counter.val()) + 1 ); // `parseInt` converts the `value` from a string to a number
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1" class="counter"/>
<button type="button" class="increment-btn">Increment</button>
```

## 'Plain' JavaScript Example

```js
var $button = document.querySelector('.increment-btn');
var $counter = document.querySelector('.counter');

$button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  $counter.value = parseInt($counter.value) + 1; // `parseInt` converts the `value` from a string to a number
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="counter" value="1"/>
<button type="button" class="increment-btn">Increment</button>
```

Comment: tagged javascript, not jquery

Comment: @gabe pretty sure more people object to using inline JavaScript click handlers in your HTML than object to jQuery. BTW, jQuery is JavaScript. The DOM isn't JavaScript though really. ;)

Comment: @paislee - Pretty sure not every situation allows for jquery. Yes I know that jquery is javascript. It a level higher though and the question was clearly tagged javascript. When you go to the store to buy cheese do you ask where the milk is? I think not.

Comment: If JavaScript is milk, then jQuery is more like 2% milk or some specific kind of milk. Make no mistake about it, jQuery is JavaScript. It is *highly* unlikely that the person who asked this question (likely very new to JS) would have thought to add the tag for jQuery. He/She might have never even heard of jQuery before.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can definitely use `onclick` or you can also use `addEventListener` to listen a click event. In this code sample the `onclick` event is in action(use).

HTML code:

```html
<div class="container">
<p><output id="output">0</output></p>
<p><button type="button" id="btn">Increment</button></p>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```js
(function() {
 var button = document.getElementById("btn")
 var output = document.getElementById("output")
 var number
 var counter
 

 function init() {
 // Convert string to primitve number using parseInt()
  number = parseInt(output.innerText)
  
 /**
 * Start counter by adding any number to start counting.
 * In this case the output starts from 0 so to immediately
 * invoke the button to increment the counter add 1 to start 
 * counting in natural number (counting numbers).
 */  counter = number + 1
  
  function increment() {
    // Increment counter
    value = counter++
    output.innerText = value
   }
  
   // Output the increment value for every click
    button.onclick = increment
 }

 window.onload = init
})()
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vw58pfar/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Increase" id="inc" onclick="incNumber()"/>
    <input type="button" value="Decrease" id="dec" onclick="decNumber()"/>

    <label id="display"></label>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var i = 0;

    function incNumber() {
        if (i < 10) {
            i++;
        } else if (i = 10) {
            i = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
    }

    function decNumber() {
        if (i > 0) {
            --i;
        } else if (i = 0) {
            i = 10;
        }
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but its relevant to what I'm working on currently.

What I'm aiming to do is create next/previous page buttons at the top of a html page, and say I'm on 'book.html', with the current 'display' ID content being 'page-1.html' through ajax, if i click the 'next' button it will load 'page-2.html' through ajax, WITHOUT reloading the page.

How would I go about doing this through AJAX as I have seen many examples but most of them are completely different, and most examples of using AJAX are for WordPress forms and stuff.

Currently using the below line will open the entire page, I want to know the best way to go about using AJAX instead if possible :)
    window.location(url);

I'm incorportating the below code as an example:

```
var i = 1;
var url = "pages/page-" + i + ".html";

    function incPage() {
    if (i < 10) {
        i++;
        window.location = url; 
        //load next page in body using AJAX request

    } else if (i = 10) {
        i = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
}

function decPage() {
    if (i > 0) {
        --i;
        window.location = url; 
        //load previous page in body using AJAX request
    } else if (i = 0) {
        i = 10;
    }
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple HTML + Thymeleaf version. Code with Controller

```
<form action="/" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${post.getId_post()}" name="id_post">
                <input type="hidden" th:value="-1" name="valueForChange">
                <input type="submit" value="-">
</form>
```

This is how it looks - look of buttons you can change with style.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b97N1.png

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry for incrementing/decrementing numbers using Javascript. Now HTML itself provides an easy way for it.

```
<input type="number" value="50">
```

It is that simple.The problem is that it works fine only in some browsers.Mozilla has not yet supported this feature.

Answer (score 0):

For those who do NOT want an input box, here's a ready-to-compile example you can check out, which just counts the button clicks, updates them in the text and toggles the font. You could take the value and use it anywhere you see fit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>
<p id="demo">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>

<script>
   function incrementValue()
        {
            var demo_id = document.getElementById('demo')
            var value = parseInt(demo_id.value, 10);
            // if NaN, set to 0, else, keep the current value
            value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
            value++;
            demo_id.value = value;

            if ((value%2)==0){
                demo_id.innerHTML = value;
                demo_id.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
                demo_id.style.color = "red";
                demo_id.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";   
            } 
            else {
                demo_id.innerHTML = value.toString() ;
                demo_id.style.fontSize = "15px"; 
                demo_id.style.color = "black";
                demo_id.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        }
</script>

<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0; 
function increment() {           
    i++;       
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```js
var timeout_;

function mouseDown_i() {
  value = isNaN(parseInt(document.getElementById('xxxx').value)) ? 0 : parseInt(document.getElementById('xxxx').value);
  document.getElementById('xxxx').value = value + 1;  
  timeout_ = setTimeout(function() { mouseDown_i(); }, 150);
}

function mouseDown_d() {
  value = isNaN(parseInt(document.getElementById('xxxx').value)) ? 0 : parseInt(document.getElementById('xxxx').value);
  value - 1 <= 0 ? document.getElementById('xxxx').value = '' : document.getElementById('xxxx').value = value - 1;  
  timeout_ = setTimeout(function() { mouseDown_d(); }, 150);
}

function mouseUp() { clearTimeout(timeout_); }

function mouseLeave() { clearTimeout(timeout_); }
```

```html
<p onmousedown="mouseDown_i()" onmouseup="mouseUp()" onmouseleave="mouseLeave()">Click to INCREMENT!</p>
<p onmousedown="mouseDown_d()" onmouseup="mouseUp()" onmouseleave="mouseLeave()">Click to DECREMENT!</p>
<input id="xxxx" type="text" value="0">
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counter = 0;

function plus() {
  counter += 1;
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
}

function minus() {
  if(counter > 0){
    counter -= 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
}
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input-box{
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button{
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

p{
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-box">
    <button type="button" onclick="minus()" style="font-size: 20px;">-</button>
    <p id="counter">0</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="plus()">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        function increment(){
            counter++;
            console.log(counter);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" onClick="increment()" value="Increment"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better. See [answer].

Answer (score -2):

jQuery Library must be in the head section then.

```
<button onclick="var less = parseInt($('#qty').val()) - 1; $('#qty').val(less);"></button>
<input type="text" id="qty" value="2">
<button onclick="var add = parseInt($('#qty').val()) + 1; $('#qty').val(add);">+</button>
```