# How can I increase value of an input field?

Tags: javascript, increment, input-field

Something that has bugged me for a while and always giving me headaches.

I have an input field with a value in numbers

```
<input id="base-life" class="base-stats" type="number" name="base-life" value="20" readonly />
```

I am picking up the value of the input field with

```
let charlife = document.getElementById('base-life');
```

I have a number with which i want to increase the value of the base-life input field. This of course changes dynamically based on other stuff but let's say it's 2

```
let increaseWith = 2;
```

in an onclick function i want to increase base-life with 2 (base-life + 2) everything it is clicked

```
function increase() {
    charlife.value += increaseWith;
}
```

Now this only adds 2 to the value of the input field, makes it 202. I know that this happens when one of the numbers are actually strings. Perhaps my charlife. I tried everything and it gets worse. I tried parseInt(charlife.value) - no luck. I tried other methods but it doesn't work. And i only have this problem with input fields. When the element is just a  or another simpler html element - it all works easier. Has to do with how JS parses input fields. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Inputs have strings as values, not numbers.

Comment: you need to parseInt the value and then add it to increment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186346/javascript-onclick-increment-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let charlife = document.getElementById('base-life');
let increaseWith = 2;
function increase() {
     value = parseInt(charlife.value);
     value += increaseWith;
     charlife.value = value;
}
```

```html
<input id="base-life" class="base-stats" type="number" name="base-life" value="20" readonly />
<button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working snippet with some custom code that is according to your specifications

```html
<input id="base-life" class="base-stats" type="number" name="base-life" value="20" readonly />
<button class="add" onclick="let increaseWith = 2;document.getElementById('base-life').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('base-life').value)+increaseWith;">add</button>
```

Comment: Ok so parseInt was still the way to go for me but i just can't use += like i though i can. Thanks for this. Tiffany's approach is with += but using additional variable. I am a bit torn on which approach is better.

Comment: There is an assignment to value also in a single line, so we can't use `+=` using `parseInt` along with it. we need to assign the expression to a variable and then assign that variable to the value of input @Tiffany did already