# increase a number when click a button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write Javascript code which can increase a number when we click a button.Can you help me?
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```js
var document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = i;
        function sum(){
            i++;
        }
```

```html
<p id="par">1</p>
<img onclick="sub()" height="40px" width="40px" src="sub.png">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript onclick increment number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186346/javascript-onclick-increment-number)

Comment: I think a few more details of your code would help to answer this, like where is your function sub() that you refer to in onclick. Maybe this is the mistake and it is supposed to be sum()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `innerHTML` upon updating the value in `sum` function.

```js
let i = 1;

document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = i;

function sum() {
  i++;
  document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = i;
}
```

```html
<p id="par">1</p>
<img onclick="sum()" height="40px" width="40px" src="sub.png">
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#increaser");
const res = document.querySelector("#result");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  res.textContent++
});
```

```html
<div>
    <p id="result">1</p>
    <button id="increaser">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you'll have to get the number that is currently displayed in your `p` tag. You can either read it from the dom every time or just keep track of it in javascript.
We should also get a reference to your p tag for later use.

```js
let i = 1;
let p = document.getElementById("par");
```

Next, when you are calling your `sub` function, you are incrementing `i`, but you are not applying the changed value to your `p` tag. You can do it like so:

```
function sum() {
  i++;
  p.innerHTML = i;
}
```

Your html can stay the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can defined a global variable to store the value, also you need make the function name keep the same

```js
        var i=0;
        function sub(){
            i++;
            document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = i;
        }
```

```html
<p id="par">1</p>
<img onclick="sub()" height="40px" width="40px" src="sub.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum() {

    var p = document.getElementById("par") ;

    p.innerHTML = parseInt(p.innerHTML) + 1 ;

}
```

```html
<p id="par">1</p>

<img onclick="sum()" height="40px" width="40px" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/452/plus.png">
```

Comment: @Sepehr Check this answer!

Answer (score -1):

function sum() {

```
var p = document.getElementById("par") ;

p.innerHTML = parseInt(p.innerHTML) + 1 ;
```

}

1

function sum() {

```
var p = document.getElementById("par") ;

p.innerHTML = parseInt(p.innerHTML) + 1 ;
```

}

1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).